# Monitoring website updates in realtime

Tags: javascript, node.js, real-time

I'm curious as how to monitor a website for it's updates in realtime, preferably in node.js.

Let's take Wikipedia for example. Someone decides to update an article with some relevant information. How would I go about subscribing to the page and instantly getting the event in my node.js server without having to poll the website every X seconds?

Comment: I don't know enough about Node.js to do this, but someone who does could see how [Hummingbird](http://projects.nuttnet.net/hummingbird/) works and apply the same concepts. I think you'd need sockets.

Comment: Make a deal with the Wikipedia people to post something to a web-based API you create whenever a page update is posted.

Comment: Think of it like stalking your ex. Either she tells you her news (highly unlikely) or you have to FETCH them.

Comment: I think you should have a look at pubsubhubbub

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, you will need to poll the website if there are no other possibilities like a news feed. You can't force them to provide such a service.

For Wikipedia in detail, there are [live update IRC streams](http://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/IRC/Channels#Recent_changes), one for each project. [Wikistream](http://wikistream.inkdroid.org/about/) is such an app that reads the feed, you can view it's open source node.js code at github.

Answer (score 2):

In case you have option to "instruct" the website to notify you, you can create webservice that website will call when it content is updated. But of course, that website should have such option.

Comment: So, you're saying there's no way to get realtime updates without the website itself offering some sort of publish/subscribe model?

Comment: @Andorenan yes - how else could it possibly work?  Either you poll the site (and polling every page on Wikipedia seems like a big challenge) or you get them to tell you via some API.