# How to find the web site page add on the page of public web site

Tags: php, angularjs, node.js

I want to get the notification if the company public web site add the document on there web sites. I need to do this for around 400 public sites. As every site will have different document directory, i will make the database for all sites directory information in Mysql at my local server.

> Example1
>
> http://www.hubpower.com
>
> The documents directory is placed in on the following path
>
> http://www.hubpower.com/wp-content/themes/hubco/pdf/
>
> There are further two documents link in the above folder:
>
> http://www.hubpower.com/wp-content/themes/hubco/pdf/3Q2K17%20Result.pdf
>   http://www.hubpower.com/wp-content/themes/hubco/pdf/1910-financial-results-announcements-(dec-2015).pdf
>
> Example2
>
> http://www.pk.abbott/investor/investor-information.html
>
> There are two documents directories is placed in on the following path
>
> http://dam.abbott.com/en-pk/documents/pdf/investors/
>   http://dam.abbott.com/en-pk/investor-relations/
>
> Here are the documents links:
>
> http://dam.abbott.com/en-pk/documents/pdf/investors/Q12017.pdf
>   http://dam.abbott.com/en-pk/investor-relations/2016Q3.pdf
>   http://dam.abbott.com/en-pk/investor-relations/Abbott_A_R_2016.pdf
>   http://dam.abbott.com/en-pk/investor-relations/AR2015.pdf

If website add any more pdf documents on above path, I would like to have  notification on email plus further download the new documents from website directory to my local server.

Please advice some solution to achieve this goal. I prefer working with 
Restful, PHP, Angularjs, Nodejs, python,Javacript

Thanks & regards

Answer (score 0):

you can use any [Website Content Changes tool](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/detect-website-change-notification/) like [Chrome Plugin Visualping](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/visualping/pemhgklkefakciniebenbfclihhmmfcd) which can email you.

[Form this Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11511894/monitoring-website-updates-in-realtime)
In general, you will need to poll the website if there are no other possibilities like a news feed. You can't force them to provide such a service.

For Wikipedia in detail, there are live update IRC streams, one for each project. Wikistream is such an app that reads the feed, you can view it's open source node.js code at github.

Comment: By using the nodejs and request module. it need the static path of the file. directory is fixed but the file name will be changed. I want to have email when file add on directory and also have the service which auto download this file

Comment: thanks for website content changes tool and chrome plugin visual ping. Apparently they will give email if page is changes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use nodejs and the [request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) module to get the html for every 400 pages you are mentioning, then you parse it with [cheerio](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cheerio), then you use [mysql](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql) module to put all the data into your database, you can also check if the data you scraped already exist in your database, if yes, you do nothing, you can do this like once a day